# CouchDB Will not start after upgrade

Tags: debian, couchdb

Tried on both 1.2.0 and 1.4.0, both error and will not start. The config files are default apart from my added user admins.

> Apache CouchDB 1.4.0 (LogLevel=info) is starting. {"init terminating
>   in
>   do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,couch_primary_services,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,collation_driver,"cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory"}}}}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,98}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, old config files are not compatible with new version.

Comment: Great answer, I hope this detail answer will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a config file problem for me as well. I used the following on OS X:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/couchdb/
brew uninstall couchdb
brew install couchdb
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by having the wrong value for util_driver_dir in the default.ini file.

Some distributions add CouchDB's version to that directory, causing old config files to fail.